# Bash variable assignment before command

Tags: bash, environment-variables

A couple of days ago I came across a command

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY="foo" AWS_SECRET_KEY="bar" aws list iam
```

I see that setting variables before a command adds those variables in the command's environment:

```
#make sure there is no environment variable "foo"
$ echo $foo

#mimic-ing above command
$ foo=bar printenv | grep foo
foo=bar

#or trying from python environment
$foo=bar python -c "import os; print(os.getenv('foo', None))"
bar

#foo is destroyed now
$ echo $foo  
#<<NOTHING
```

I was trying to use this trick to dynamically create a new directory based on today's date:

```
$ dname=$(date +%d_%m_%y) mkdir ${dname} && cd ${dname}
```

but I got following error:

```
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
```

i.e. `dname=$(date +%d_%m_%y) echo $dname` returns empty!

What am I doing wrong? How can I dynamically create and use are variable on the same line in bash?

Comment: Arguments come from the current shell, not the environment in which the command will eventually be run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell is substituting your variable before running the command inside `$()`.  You can use `&&` to make it work for you:

```
dname=$(date +%d_%m_%y) && mkdir ${dname} && cd ${dname}
```

or, of course:

```
dname=$(date +%d_%m_%y); mkdir ${dname} && cd ${dname}
```

However, `dname` would be available to `mkdir` if it were to grab the environment variable inside.

Let's say we have a script `test.sh` that has a single statement `echo $dname` inside. Then:

```
dname=$(date +%d_%m_%y) ./test.sh
```

would yield:

```
07_03_17
```

This is consistent with how your `aws` command line worked.

---

Similar posts:

- [How do I set an environment variable on the command line and have it appear in commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c)

Comment: This is different in that it sets `dname` for the remainder of this script (or until explicitly unset, of course). Perhaps in practice you would want to define a function which does `mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"` and then call it with your value as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `&&` before mkdir below is complete statement you desire:

`dname=$(date +%d_%m_%y) && mkdir ${dname} && cd ${dname}`

Also if its not necessary to declare `dname` you can do:
`mkdir $(date +%d_%m_%y) && cd ${dname}` both will give same answer